# Train route database design for Vs 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, database-design

Help! Not sure if this question has been asked or not,
I'm creating a visual basic application that finds out trains between two given stations, and displays all such trains. Also if selected the route between those stations must be displayed. The front end was quite simple, now stuck not knowing what to do , please give me some idea's or hints.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you're using a relational database.  This requires a [relational data model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_data_model).

You have stations, so your first table is station.  Database table names are usually singular.  This table holds all the information about a station.

What connects stations together?  Track segments.  So now, your next table is track segment.  A track segment ties two stations together.

Next, you have trains.  So now you have a train table.  This table contains information about the train itself.

Now, you have to associate the trains with the stations.  A train passes through many stations (usually), and a station sees many trains pass through.  This is what's known as a [many to many relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29).

You create an associative table that ties trains and stations together.  This table also holds the time stamp of when the train arrives and the time stamp of when the train leaves the station.

This should be enough to get you started.  If you have a specific question about your data model, feel free to ask another Stack Overflow question.